# JS - deleting object from array

Tags: javascript

I want to delete one object (index) from my table/array

```
var item = [
{name:'test1',variable:20},
{name:'test2',variable:20},
{name:'test3',variable:20},
{name:'test4',variable:20},
{name:'test5',variable:20},
{name:'test6',variable:20},
{name:'test7',variable:20},
{name:'test8',variable:20}]
```

for example i want to delete object number 2 (item.name=test3), how i can do it?

Comment: What do you want to happen to the remaining objects in the array? Do you want them to keep their indices or do you want them to move down to fill the gap?

Comment: i want to set new amount of index

Comment: I do not understand why you are downcasting, there has not been a question about deleting an index for a given property of an object in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `splice()` and `findIndex()` methods.

```js
var item = [{name:'test1',variable:20},{name:'test2',variable:20},{name:'test3',variable:20},{name:'test4',variable:20},{name:'test5',variable:20},{name:'test6',variable:20},{name:'test7',variable:20},{name:'test8',variable:20}]

item.splice(item.findIndex(({name}) => name == 'test3'), 1);
console.log(item)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply call:

```
delete item[2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option...

```
item = item.filter(e=>e.name!=="test3")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use splice , but be carefull since it modifies the actual array

```js
var item = [
{name:'test1',variable:20},
{name:'test2',variable:20},
{name:'test3',variable:20},
{name:'test4',variable:20},
{name:'test5',variable:20},
{name:'test6',variable:20},
{name:'test7',variable:20},
{name:'test8',variable:20}]

item.splice(2,1)

console.log(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function remove(array, element) {
    return array.filter(e => e !== element);
}

const vowelsAndX = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "x"];
const vowels = remove(vowelsAndX, "x");
vowels.toString(); // "a,e,i,o,u"

----------------------------------------------------------------------------


var item = [
    {name:'test1',variable:20},
    {name:'test2',variable:20},
    {name:'test3',variable:20},
    {name:'test4',variable:20},
    {name:'test5',variable:20},
    {name:'test6',variable:20},
    {name:'test7',variable:20},
    {name:'test8',variable:20}];

    function remove(array, element) {
        return array.filter(e => e !== element);
    }

    const restOfItems = remove(item, item[0]);
    console.log(restOfItems)
```

Comment: did you tried your solution with the actual array provided the OP wants to remove in object from the array i.e `{name:'test1',variable:20},` or any other like given in the array of objects

Comment: It's a matter of logic to do the update for the request example.
I made update for the example in question
link: https://jsfiddle.net/7n6z7e4c/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
var item = [
{name:'test1',variable:20},
{name:'test2',variable:20},
{name:'test3',variable:20},
{name:'test4',variable:20},
{name:'test5',variable:20},
{name:'test6',variable:20},
{name:'test7',variable:20},
{name:'test8',variable:20}]

//removing 1 element from number 2
var removeObj = item.splice(2,1);

console.log(item);
```